# why does my wordpress home button redirect to the original template?

Tags: themes

im using vinsmoke as a wordpress template: vu-amp.org
when i click on the home button in the menu, it takes me back to the OG vinsmoke with all the lorel ipsum. how do i make it not do that

Comment: You'll have to ask the theme's support team. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Your home link is pointing to a different website. You need to edit the menu to change the link. This does not require development. I suggest trying the WordPress.org support forums for help.